# How to read TimePicker chosen values?

Tags: android, timepicker

I followed this guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html
im not quite sure what goes where with this (im faily new to android dev)
I have a package with both my mainActivity class and the timepicker class.
i want that when time is set, to write it to mainactivity's variables, or the other way around, to do that "onTimeSet" saves values as class variables and read those vars from my mainActivity.
How do i do that?

Here's my fragment class:

```
package com.example.remoteswitch;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                            implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    int hour, min;
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, true);
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
        hour = hourOfDay;
        min = minute;

    }
}
```

from my MainActivity class, I have a function that is called when a button is pressed:

```
public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
            //DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
            TimePickerFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker"); 

            //todo: read values from timePicker
            int pickerHour = 0, pickerMin = 0;
            //some manipulations on this data
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? The Developer's Guide that you linked to gives you a basic, but complete example. You could simply save those values in field / class variables.

Comment: i could do that on "onTimeSet", but how do i read those from this class? I have the `showTimePickerDialog` that shows the timePicker window, but i dont understand how to read this object's values afterwards

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Rewrite**
I combined both of the examples from the Developer's Guides that we discussed.  Now you should be able to understand how to send the time that user chooses from the TimePickerFragment back to the Activity where it is more useful.  (I made some changes from the first example.)

TimePickerFragment:

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
    // Notice I removed "implements OnTimeSetListener" and changed the variables

    private Activity mActivity;
    private OnTimeSetListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mActivity = activity;

        // This error will remind you to implement an OnTimeSetListener 
        //   in your Activity if you forget
        try {
            mListener = (OnTimeSetListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnTimeSetListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it

        // I made a couple changes here!
        return new TimePickerDialog(mActivity, mListener, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(mActivity));
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
// add "implements OnTimeSetListener" to "public class MainActivity ..."
private int pickerHour = 0;
private int pickerMin = 0;

// onCreate() and your other methods...

public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    TimePickerFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker"); 
}    

@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    // Do something with the time chosen by the user
    pickerHour = hourOfDay;
    pickerMin = minute;
}
```

Comment: Yes, That is great, and i did that. but i cant understand how, after i did newfragment.show(), how do i read those hour,minute, from my mainActivity class. that is my desire, to know these values after the user sets them

Comment: Ok, I understand your question now. Create your `onTimeSet()` listener in MainActivity and pass it to the Fragment. This is described in [Communicating with the Activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity). (They use a custom listener in their example, but the process is the same.)

Comment: I read that page but cant really understand how to do it. Im very new to fragments. Im more familiar with dialogs, which is very straight forward, but i cant realize how it works with fragments.

Comment: Ok, please click ["edit"](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15027987/edit) under your question to post how you create and show your TimePickerFragment. It is easier to help you with code you are actually using.

Comment: At the moment I havent modified it too much. I have a package with MainActivity.java & TimePickerFragment class, simply a copy-paste from the dev site

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: I dont. you'r the best :-) I need to refresh my java skills...its completely non-android related eventually, its been 2 years since my last java app..anyway thanks alot! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use below answer. This worked for me.

Interface Class:

```
public interface OnTimeSetListener {
    void onTimeSet(String time);
}
```

Activity Class onClick:

```
        DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment(getActivity(), this);
        newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
```

Overide the interface listener method:

```
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(String time) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//do something here to set the values
    }
```